# Select record in update mode in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using this to select record

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> SelectEmployeeById(int id)
{
  DataClassesHrPortalDataContext dc1 = new DataClassesHrPortalDataContext(dbConnStr);
  System.Data.Linq.Table<Employee> location = dc1.GetTable<Employee>();

  return dc1.Employees.Where(a => a.emp_id == id);

}
```

but how i can retrieve the record in
But how i can fill the record in textbox

```
private void fillsalarydetail()
{
  PioneerDataAccess.EmployeeClass empcls = new PioneerDataAccess.EmployeeClass();

  var obj = empcls.SelectEmployeeById(3);

  //I am not able to do this
  txtSalEmpName.Text=obj.
  txtsalempcode.Text=
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of **linq differed execution** make use of tolist method and than get read data will do you task

```
var obj = empcls.SelectEmployeeById(3).ToList(); 
textvox.Text= obj[0].Nameofproperty;
```

Comment: Now How i can assign the value in textbox

Comment: @piushshukla - textvox.Text=    obj[0].Nameofproperty

Answer (score 2):

.Where extension Method return IEnumerable List. so get The Top element or get Single Element from list.

```
EmployeeClass Emp  = empcls.SelectEmployeeById(3).ToList();  
if(listofEmp.Count() > 0)
{
EmployeeClass obj = listofEmp[0]; 
or 
EmployeeClass obj = listofEmp.Top(1);
or 
EmployeeClass obj = listofEmp.Single();

//then assign your values to testbox use class properties as:

txtSalEmpName.Text=obj.Name;
txtsalempcode.Text= obj.code;
}
```

---

You can do this as:

```
EmployeeClass Emp  = empcls.SelectEmployeeById(3).SingleOrDefault();
if(Emp != null)
{
txtSalEmpName.Text=obj.Name;
txtsalempcode.Text= obj.code;
}
```